# gerando uma array de [mês/ano] p/ enviar para um ajax

Tags: javascript, html

não tenho certeza se especifiquei o título corretamente, mas, vamos lá, tenho uma url que retorna uma json com um valor do banco, o valor vem desta maneira: "01/2010" até "12/2016". criei um loop que me traz desta maneira: `val['01/2010']`.

esse é o json:

[image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]

gostaria de uma maneira de não ter que escrever essas datas direto no codigo, mas de gerar dinamicamente e colocar dentro do meu loop. segue o fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xey416mp/

Comment: Pelo que estou a perceber pelo "`val['01/2010']`" então `'01/2010'` é a chave e não o valor

Comment: @Miguel é isso mesmo

Comment: quere a chave portanto, como está o seu loop? Pelo codigo que mostrou o que deve usar lá é o key

Comment: Formata seu Json, com algo do tipo `[
  {"Data":"01/2010"},
  {"Data":"02/2010"},
 {"Data":"03/2010"}
]`

Answer (score 3):

Leandro, para percorrer um json, basta fazer assim.:

```js
var data = {
  CURSO: "",
  SITUACAO: "",
  TOTAL_FINANCIAMENTO: "",
  SEMESTRES_FINANCIADOS: "",
  VALOR_FINANCIADO_SEM: "",
  DATA_REPASSE: "",
  '01/2010': 0.00,
  '02/2010': 0.00,
  '03/2010': 0.00,
  '04/2010': 0.00,
  '05/2010': 0.00,
  '06/2010': 0.00,
  '07/2010': 0.00,
  '08/2010': 0.00,
  '09/2010': 0.00,
  '10/2010': 0.00,
  '11/2010': 0.00,
  '12/2010': 0.00
};

var isDate = function (text) {
  var date = new Date("01/" + text);
  return date && !isNaN(date) && date != "Invalid Date"
}

for (var key in data) {
  var value = data[key];
  if (isDate(key)) {
    console.log(key, value);
  }
}
```

Note que no seu caso em especifico, além de percorrer as chaves do objeto, você deve verificar se a chave representa uma data.

Answer (score 2):

Assim como @TobyMosque disse, portanto, se quiser iteratar sequencialmente as datas, você pode fazer assim:

```
var dates = {};

for (var key in val) {
    var index = key.indexOf("/"),
        year = key.substr(index + 1);
    /* checa se o ano já não foi definido e
       checa se key aparenta ser uma data */
    if (!dates[year] && index !== -1)
        dates[year] = {};
}

for (key in val) {
    var index = key.indexOf("/");
    /* checa se key aparenta ser uma data */
    if (index !== -1)
        dates[key.substr(index + 1)][key.substr(0, index)] = val[key];
}
```

Agora você pode iteratar normalmente a array `dates` e concatenar os dados dos meses:

```
var html = "";
for (var year of dates) {
    for (var month of year) {
        html += '<td align="right">' + month + '</td>';
    }
}

$('#resultAluno tbody').append('<tr><td>' +
    val.CURSO + '</td> <td>' +
    val.SITUACAO + '</td><td align="right">' +
    val.TOTAL_FINANCIAMENTO + '</td><td align="right">' +
    val.SEMESTRES_FINANCIADOS + '</td><td align="right">' +
    val.DATA_REPASSE + '</td>' + html + "</tr>"
);
```

Comment: desculpe a resposta tardia, estava enrolado, mas voltando ao assunto, aquele ```for()``` eu vou colocar dentro do meu $.each? conforme o jsfiddle ja passado?

Comment: @Leandro Sim, no escopo onde tem `val`.

Comment: ta dando erro na linha onde ficou sobrando um ")" onde tem a variavel ```html +=```

Comment: @Leandro Foi mal! Coloquei aquele `)` sem querer...